# Cannot open SDL support on Qemu

Tags: arm, sdl, qemu

When I compile qemu for arm platform, I configure as follows:

```
./configure --cross-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabi- --target-list=arm-softmmu --enable-kvm --enable-sdl --static
```

But get errors below:

```
ERROR: User requested feature sdl ERROR: configure was not able to find it
```

I don't know what's wrong
I use Ubuntu 12.04 with libsdl1.2dev on it
I download the source code of qemu from its official site

Comment: Any "fedora" version of this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is one of 3 stages I had to pass in my journey to compile *qemu* for *raspberry pi* emulation on Ubuntu.
SDL gets solved running on console:

```
apt-get install libsdl-dev-image1.2-dev
```

And then the next issue you will undoubtedly have:

```
git submodule update --init pixman
```

Comment: Is there an extra "dev" in the suggested package name?  I cannot find the suggested package on 16.04 but there is a libsdl-image1.2-dev which also seems to be in precise http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libsdl-image1.2-dev

Answer (score 1):

If:

```
    apt-get install libsdl-dev-image1.2-dev
```

doesn't work, then try:

```
    apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed the following packages from http://www.libsdl.org/ (I run CentOS 6).

> $ rpm -i SDL-1.2.15-1.i386.rpm

then

> $ rpm -i SDL-devel-1.2.15-1.i386.rpm

which did the trick.